# how to Fix Pagination using PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

hi everyone i am trying to create my pagination in below format

Go to Page 3 [text-box] Previous 1 2 3 4 5 ....400 Next

and below is my code

```
             if(isset($_REQUEST['limit_start']) && $_REQUEST['limit_start'] > 0) $limit_start = $_REQUEST['limit_start'];
        else  $limit_start = 0 ;
        if(isset($_REQUEST['results_to_show']) )  $results_to_show= $_REQUEST['results_to_show'];
        else $results_to_show = 100;

        if(($limit_start-$results_to_show)>=0)
        $pagination.='<a href="details-inventory.php?limit_start='.($limit_start-$results_to_show).'&&results_to_show='.$results_to_show.'" >Previous</a> | ';

          if (isset($_REQUEST['submit']) && $_REQUEST['submit'] != "")$search_limited = 1;
          else $search_limited = 0;

        global $wpdb;
        $sql='SELECT count(*) 
        FROM `inventory_location` ';

        $data= $wpdb->get_results($sql,ARRAY_A);
         $row_count= $data[0]['count(*)']; 

        for($number=(($limit_start/$results_to_show)+1);$number<($row_count/$results_to_show);$number++)//($row_count/$results_to_show);$number++)($limit_start/$results_to_show)+
        $pagination.= '<a href="details-inventory.php?limit_start='.($number*$results_to_show).'&&results_to_show='.$results_to_show.'" >'.$number.'</a> | ';

        $pagination.= ' <a href="details-inventory.php?limit_start='.($limit_start+$results_to_show).'&&results_to_show='.$results_to_show.'" >Next </a> <br />';
```

Now the problem is this ..... 
it show all the numbers from 1 to last page ... i want to break it in below style

```
   1 2 3 4 5 ....400
```

thanx

Comment: `&&results_to_show` is this a typo? you used all over

Comment: @Atif Azad are you using WordPress

Comment: yes i am using wordpress

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using WordPress there is an inbuilt function `paginate_links` for pagination.

You can view more info on the same here :http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links .

Rather than creating your own, it will be good to use inbuilt function which does the same functionality what you need.

This will help you to suit your needs. You just need to pass the correct arguments. `mid_size` is the argument you need to specify how many page numbers should be shown to either side of current page, but not including current page.

**UPDATE :**

You code can be simplified like below :

```
global $wpdb;

//get the total count
$total_count = $wpdb->get_var('SELECT count(*) FROM `inventory_location`');

//number of results to be shown per page
$results_to_show_per_page   = 100;

//specify the number of page numbers to be shown on each side of the current page
$mid_size = 3;

//check whether the query argument page is set and get the current page
if (isset($_GET['page']))
    $page = abs((int)$_GET['page']);
else
    $page = 1;

//generate page links
$pagination_links = paginate_links( array(
                            'base' => add_query_arg( 'page', '%#%' ),
                            'total' => ceil($total_count / $results_to_show_per_page),
                            'current' => $page,
                            'mid_size'=> $mid_size 
                    ));


echo $pagination_links;
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: thanx sabari actually i am new with wordpress  ... no idea how to use it. would you pls tell me how would i use here in my code paginate_links code from your provided link